# What is the solution to this Riccati equation $ ' =  ^2 + f(x)$ on $[0,\infty)$, where $f$ is an arbitrary increasing function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you give me a hint about how I can solve the Riccati equation $ ' =  ^2 + f(x)$ on $[0,\infty)$, where $f$ is an arbitrary increasing function? I know this can be solved for simple cases such as $f(x) = b x^n$. Are there any results for general increasing functions?

Context: When you write the Bellman equation of a drift rate control problem (of a one-dimensional Brownian motion) with an average cost criterion, you get this Riccati equation. Finding a closed-form solution to this differential equation would help in solving the drift rate control problem.

Comment: You know about the substitution $y=-\frac{u'}{au}$ and the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem which should allow to bound the first root of $u''(x)+af(x)u(x)=0$ which is the pole of $y$ where it explodes towards infinity?

Answer (score 2):

$$y'=ay^2+f(x)$$
See the change of function Eq.$(5)$in :  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiccatiDifferentialEquation.html
$$y(x)=\frac{z'}{-a\,z(x)}$$
$$y'=\frac{z''}{-a\,z}+\frac{z'^2}{a\,z^2}=a\left(\frac{z'}{-a\,z(x)}\right)^2+f(x)$$
After simplification :
$$z''+a\,f(x)\,z=0$$
This is a linear second order ODE. See Eq.$(25)$ in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Second-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html

The possibility to solve it for $z(x)$ on a closed form depends on what kind of function $f(x)$ is.

Comment: Thank you. It seems like I can solve this for $f(x) = e^{\alpha x}$ and $f(x) = \alpha x^n$ for $\alpha > 0$. Do you know of other increasing functional forms that I can solve this for?

Comment: For example $f(x)=\frac{-1}{1+\exp(b^2x+c)}$ .